# how to interpret log fold change (log2FC) on two cases

Tags: bioinformatics, statistical-test

just quick bioinformatic question if possible.
I did read few papers and could not understand what this log fold change means.
to make it simple I have a log2 fold change(log2FC) value 2 between condition A and B.
Does it mean A is two times higher compared to B or A is two times smaller compared to B?

Thank you.

Comment: This type of question is not on-topic for stackoverflow (refer to the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help)) and would be better suited to  https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that for gene expression the logFC of B relative to A is 2.
If `log2(FC) = 2`, the real increase of gene expression from A to B is 4 (2^2) (`FC = 4`). In other words, A has gene expression four times lower than B, which means at the same time that B has gene expression 4 times higher than A.